# How do I reveal a hidden row based on a cell value?

Tags: validation, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

I have created a sheet which has a dropdown with values "Select One:" "Push" "Pull" in cell B23.  I would like row 24 to be hidden by default.  Upon selection of the value "Pull" from the dropdown, I would like row 24 to be unhidden.

Is there a way to unhide row 24 if the selection in cell B23 = Pull?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to:

- Show row 24 if dropdown in `B23` is set to `Pull`.
- Hide row 24 in any other case.

If that's the case, you can copy this simple `onEdit` trigger to the script [bound to your spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) (the sheet with the data is called `Sheet1` in this sample, please change this accordingly if that's not the case):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please change accordingly
  var dropdown = sheet.getRange("B23").getValue();
  var row = 24;
  if (dropdown == "Pull") sheet.showRows(row);
  else sheet.hideRows(row);
}
```

As you can see, there is no need to use a `for` loop, which will slow down the execution (specially considering this will run every time the file is edited).

In order to make sure row 24 will be hidden or shown accordingly the first time you open your file, you can attach an `onOpen` trigger to the function, like this:

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  onEdit(e)
}
```

#### Reference:

- [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene)
- [hideRows(rowIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex)
- [showRows(rowIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showrowsrowindex)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Hi lamlichus, thank you for your reply.  When I execute the script in the script editor I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (Line 4, file "showRow".

I don't know enough about google sheets to know if I'm not connecting the script properly or how to further troubleshoot the error.  Any advice?

Comment: @JamesKrueger Most probably this is happening because the sheet name in the code (called `Sheet1` in the sample I provided) doesn't match the actual sheet name. Please check that.

Comment: @JamesKrueger notice what the error is saying. Cannot call method `getRange` of null. Where are you calling `getRange` from? From the variable `sheet`. So `sheet` is null. Which means that `ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")` returns null. Which means there is no sheet called `Sheet1` in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hmm. I renamed the sheet to "Sheet1" to mimic you script as close as possible. I do not believe this error is due to the sheet name.

Comment: I was wondering if I'm missing a method to link the script to the sheet.  I clicked Tools > Script Editor. Pasted the contents of the script into the editor > Saved the script > Reloaded both pages to ensure naming conventions were not an issue and still return :null error.  How does the script know where to look for "Sheet1"?

Comment: @JamesKrueger the script gets the spreadsheet to which it is bound this way: `SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`. Well that's very strange. Are you sure it's the same name? `Sheet1`? Not `Sheet 1`, or similar? If you cannot make this to work, please share the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information) and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Solved. It was the individual sheet name (bottom left). Not the spreadsheet title (top left.  This works great now, thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @JamesKrueger you're most welcome. The spreadsheet is the file; the sheets are the different "tabs" in the file.

Answer (score 0):

use this script:

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var xx=sh.getRange("B23").getValue();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    var row=i+1;
    switch(xx)
    {
      case 'Pull':
        if(row=24){sh.showRows(row);}
        break;
      case 'Select One:':
        if(row=24){sh.hideRows(row);}
        break;
      case 'Push':
        if(row=24){sh.hideRows(row);}
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
}
```